# Javax.print monochrome doesn't work

Tags: java, pdf, printing, icepdf

I'm developing an application that uses `javax.print` and `icepdf`.

When I try to print a colored PDF in black and white, my printer always prints it in color...

I have used theses properties:

```
printRequestAttributeSet.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);
hasDocAttributeSet.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);
```

But my printer still print this in color.

How to print a colored pdf in black and white?

Comment: is this possible with javax.print and icepdf ?